# Matching objects inside an array with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm testing with sinon.js a method call that takes an array of objects, something like this:

```
let f = function(arr) {}

f([{foo: "bar"}, {baz: "quux"}];
```

And i want to perform assertions on the content of the call to `f` in my test using [sinon matchers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/matchers/).

I have a spy on `f`, called `fSpy`, and i can already do

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(fSpy);
sinon.assert.calledWith(fSpy, sinon.match.array);
```

However, if i test for something like

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(fSpy, sinon.match.array.contains(sinon.match.has("foo")));
```

The test fails.

I'm guessing this is because the arguments for matchers cannot be matchers themselves, so what is the proper way to test this?

Comment: Yes but sinon matchers work only if passed as arguments to sinon functions AFAIK, so passing it to `contains` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stub replacing the method implementation and move the assertions for the arguments inside that method.

```
sinon.stub(an_object, 'a_method', function(args) {
  expect(args)....
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hitting your head against the **'matchers'** wall - which is fairly limited unless you provide a custom matcher - I'd suggest you follow the clean and easy path, like so.

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

var sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);

chai.use(SinonChai);
chai.should();


context('Test', () => {

  this.f = function(arr) {

  };


  beforeEach(() => {
    if (!this.sandbox) {
      this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    } else {
      this.sandbox.restore();
    }
  });


  it('should pass the test',
    (done) => {

      const fSpy = this.sandbox.spy(this, 'f');

      this.f([{
        foo: 'bar'
      }, {
        baz: 'quux'
      }]);


      fSpy.should.have.been.calledOnce;
      fSpy.should.have.been.calledWith(sinon.match.array);

      const args = fSpy.getCall(0).args[0];
      args.should.have.deep.include.any.members([{foo: 'bar'}]);
      args.should.have.deep.property('[0].foo', 'bar');
      args.should.have.deep.property('[1].baz', 'quux');

      done();
    });

});
```

Get access to the arguments passed into the method on the first call and use any assertion library directly on that input.  It's straightforward and your options are not limited.

Comment: That would be a good solution, but i cannot use it since i'm actually testing a function that calls `f` internally, not a direct call to `f`.